# Tool to apply XSL to XSD?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL file and an XSD file on my local disk.

The XSL file is supposed to transform the XSD file to OWL format.

What freeware tool can I use apply this transformation? Thanks.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my amswer for a complete list of all XSLT processors and IDEs that I know about.

Answer (score 7):

> The XSL file is supposed to transform
>   the XSD file to OWL format.
>
> What freeware tool can I use apply
>   this transformation?

You can use any existing free XSLT processor, but it should implement the version of XSLT as specified of the `version` attribute of the `<xsl:stylesheet>` (top) element of the stylesheet module.

**Here is a rather incomplete list of such XSLT processors**:

**XSLT 1.0 processors**:

1. **MSXML [3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28494391-052b-42ff-9674-f752bdca9582)/[4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3144b72b-b4f2-46da-b4b6-c5d7485f2b42)/[6](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=993c0bcf-3bcf-4009-be21-27e85e1857b1)**.
2. **[Saxon 6.5.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/saxon6/6.5.5/saxon6-5-5.zip/download)**
3. **[XML-Spy (AltovaXML)](http://www.download3k.com/Web-Authoring/XML-CSS-Utilities/Download-AltovaXML.html)**.
4. **.[NET XslTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.aspx)**.
5. .**[NET XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)**.
6. **[LibXMl/LibXSLT](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/)**.
7. **[JD](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/xmltools/prod/jd.xslt.html)**.
8. **[Xalan/C](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/overview.html)** or **[Xalan/J](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/)**.

**XSLT 2.0 processors**

1. **[Saxon 9.x](http://sf.net/projects/saxon)**.
2. **[AltovaXML2010](http://www.download3k.com/Web-Authoring/XML-CSS-Utilities/Download-AltovaXML.html)**.
3. **[XQSharp (Beta)](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/beta.htm)**.
4. **[IBM WebSphere XML Pack](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/featurepacks/xml/)** (not free).
5. **[Intel® SOA Expressway XSLT 2.0 Processor](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-soa-expressway-xslt-20-processor/)** (not free).

**XSLT IDEs**

1. **MS Visual Stusio (2010 or 2008)** -- works only with XslCompiledTransform
2. **[oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)** -- works with all mentioned XSLT processors
3. **[XSelerator](http://sf.net/projects/xselerator)** -- works with all mentioned XSLT processors
4. **[Kernow](http://kernowforsaxon.sourceforge.net/)**: simple, Java-based IDE for Saxon.

Comment: I would add a note about [MSXSL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) next to MSXML. It's a small (24KB) command line wrapper for XSLT transformations done by MSXML, available directly. What's unusual for MS, you don't have to download 600MB package to get this tool.

Comment: @jarekczek, Sure, but here I am listing the available XSLT processors -- not their command-line utilitites -- which almost all of them have. msxsl.exe isn't a separate XSLT processor and isn't a separate XSLT IDE.

Answer (score 2):

[Kernow](http://kernowforsaxon.sourceforge.net/) is a good free tool for applying XSLT transformations. It's java-based.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Saxon http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Not that XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 are two different transformation languages. You should check the namespace used in the XSL file to find out if you need an XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 processor (the most probable answer is '1.0').

Your web browser already has an XSLT 1.0 processor, though it may not be convenient to use it. You have to modify the input document (XSD in your case) to add the following line at the top (where *`xsd2owl.xsl`* is the path to your XSLT). Then, you just have to open the file with the browser.

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="xsd2owl.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
```

Also, [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) is the Libxslt-based command-line tool that does XSLT 1.0 tranformation and has some EXSLT extensions. You'll find it packaged for every Linux distribution. [Follow this link for Windows downloads](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html).

Answer (score 0):

Quick start with **XSLT 1.0** on:

**Windows**

Download [MSXSL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714). A small (24KB) command line utility that makes use of a library you already have on your system (msxml). Run `msxsl.exe`.

**Linux**

```
apt-get xsltproc
xsltproc
```