# Is there a web site that does XSLT transformations and provides a URL as a result?

Tags: xslt, web-applications

I would like to use Foursquare API XML results and transform them using XSLT to a RSS feed. I was wondering if there's any web site that has that functionality and generates a URL that returns the final transformation.

Something like:

- From URL: http://foursquare.com/myapicall + XSLT transformation
- I get a new URL: http://transformer/url=http://server.com/myapiresult&xlst=XXX
- that returns the resulting transformation

Any other ideas to achieve this are welcome!

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you shouldn't use someone else bandwidth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The W3C hosts an **XSLT 2.0**  [**Online XSLT Servlet Service**](http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/) that can be used to transform files.

http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt

In addition to using the form, **you can also invoke the [XSLT servlet](http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/xslt) by formulating a URL with two querystring parameters**: 1. `xmlfile` to specify the source XML and 2. `xslfile` the XSLT to apply:

The results of the transform are returned from the request to the URL.

For example:
http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/xslt?xmlfile=http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss&xslfile=http://interglacial.com/rss/smb_rss2html.xsl

> **Conditions for Use**
>
> This service is provided without
>   warranty.
>
> This service is freely ([show your
>   support](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/sup)) provided for interactive use
>   by individuals only and not to be
>   utilized as a regular service by sites
>   other than w3.org. We will consider
>   blocking high volume usage or any
>   usage that causes a strain on our Web
>   servers.
>
> Abuses of this service will be
>   deterred, please report any incidents.
>   To deter this service being utilized
>   by spammers, [SURBL](http://www.surbl.org/) [is implemented](http://dev.w3.org/cvsweb/java/classes/org/w3c/app/util/BlacklistChecker.java).
>
> You may also wish to install the
>   [application](http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/SaxonSavvyServlet.java) locally rather than using
>   the W3C service. For your convenience
>   a compiled version of this servlet and
>   the org.w3c classes used are [collected
>   into a jar](http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/SaxonSavvyServlet.jar).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but these sites offer online XSLT transformations, showing the results in the browser:

- http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog
- http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there's any web
>   site that has that functionality and
>   generates a URL that returns the final
>   transformation.

While there may be sites that offer such functionality, this is by definition limited to a certain XSLT processor and comes with limited functionality (for example it is likely that DTDs and functions as `document()` are not supported, as well as EXSLT and other useful libraries).

Also, do not expect such sites to be responsive, as it is extremely easy to suffocate any such site -- just commit an error that results in endless recursion.

**Therefore, I recommend getting a good XSLT processor and performing the transformation on your own computer**.

See my answer to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800725/tool-to-apply-xsl-to-xsd/3801116#3801116)** for available free XSLT processors and environments.